# How are these two solutions for $\int \cot x\,dx$ equivalent?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, logarithms

The cotangent function is usually integrated by simple substitution.

$$\tag{1} \int \cot(x)\,dx = \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\,dx$$

Seting $u=\sin x$, we get $du = \cos x \, dx$. Plugging this in, we get an integral, which we can easily solve. Substituting $u$ back, we get a solution:

$$\tag{2} \int \frac{1}{u}\,du = \ln|u| + C = \ln|\sin x| + C$$

---

However, we get a seemingly different result if we choose a different $u$. If we set $u = \cos x$ and plug $du = -\sin x\,dx$ into the original expression $(3)$, we get:

$$\tag{3.1} -\int \frac{u}{1-u^2}\,du$$

With another substitution, setting $v = 1 - u^2$ and plugging in $dv = -2u\,du$, we can solve the integral. Pluging $u$ and $v$ back, we get a solution.

$$\tag{3.1} \int \frac{1}{2v}\,dv = \frac{\ln|v|}{2} + C = \frac{\ln|\sin^2x|}{2} + C$$

---

The two solutions are equivalent, even according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%20lnabs(sin%5E2x)%20%3D%20lnabs(sinx)), yet I find it difficult to see how. I would be most thankful if someone could show their equality $(4)$.

$$\tag{4} \ln|\sin x| = \frac{\ln|\sin^2x|}{2} + C$$

---

Thanks to the comments by [Ak19](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/668124/ak19) and [Peter Foreman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631494/peter-foreman), I now see how the equality holds. We just rewrite the second solution (without the constant) like so $(5)$.

$$\tag{5} \frac{\ln|\sin^2x|}{2} = \frac{\ln|{e^{2\ln|\sin x|}}|}{2} = \ln|e^{\ln|\sin x|}| = \ln|\sin x|$$

Comment: Hint: $\ln(|x|^a) = a\ln| x|$

Comment: Oh, that would answer my question, but where does the equality come from?

Comment: That equality is equivalent to the statement$$(b^c)^d=b^{cd}$$See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) list.

Comment: Thank you both, it got it a moment after replying to the first comment. Should I post the answer to the question below?

Comment: I would suggest to edit your question and add the answer at the bottom. But if you still wish to post it separately, then it's your choice : )

Comment: I did it. Thank you again for responding so quickly. Even when simple like in this case, sometimes I just fail to see something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both the results obtained are the same 
$$\frac{\ln|\sin^2 x|}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\ln|\sin x|^2}{2}$$
$$=\frac{2\ln|\sin x|}{2}$$
$$=\ln|\sin x|$$

Comment: The question was already answered in the comments. Perhaps you could mention who already answered it and copy the last part of my question which already contains the answer? Otherwise, I can't really accept it.

Comment: But your result $\ln(\sin x)$ is undefined for $x\le0$. Didn't you forget to use Mode i.e. $\ln|\sin x|$ instead of $\ln(\sin x)$?

Comment: The way you answered is different from mine. So how can you say mine is a copy of your answer? I mean I haven't used any exponential function which you used in your answer, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't imply your answer is a copy, I just suggested you copy the already existing answer and mention who answered the question first (in the comments).